# js textbox value decided the button onclick event happens in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Now I encounter a problem. I did some validation for a textbox, I want an effect that only when user enters correct information, the button could do onclick event. If users did not enter correct, the button should not do onclick event(no submit, only use js and button).

```
<input type="text" id="eventsPostcodeTextbox" runat="server" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" />
<input type="button" id="eventsButton" runat="server" value="FIND" onclick="search()" /> 

function showHint(str) {
     reg = /^(0[289][0-9]{2})|([1345689][0-9]{3})|(2[0-8][0-9]{2})|(290[0-9])|(291[0-4])|(7[0-4][0-9]{2})|(7[8-9][0-9]{2})$/;
     if (str.length == 0) {
         document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
         return false;
     } else if (str.length == 4 && reg.test(str)) {
         document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
         return;
     } else {
         document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "Your input is not correct.";
         return false;
     }
 }
```

In **search()**, I use ajax to draw a datatable. Now it is no matter what input, it will get the data of textbox, if the data is not correct, it will give error.

Comment: Could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/umjss8jn/2/

Comment: Hi, I tried in jsfiddle, but not work....

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var showHintResult;
$('#eventsPostcodeTextbox').keyup(function (){
    showHintResult = showHint($(this).val())
});

$('#eventsButton').on('click', function(e){
    if (!showHintResult) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    search();
});
```

`e.preventDefault()` prevents the default behavior for button "*click*".

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution. No matter enter what, the button could not call the search() function. And I tried to console.log(showHintResult); But no any data.

Comment: @GuodongRong did you add it to `#eventsButton` click event...check the updated answer